# Как запретить доступ к файлам?

Tags: apache

Добавил Options -Indexes что бы запретить гулять по файлам сервера, но остался еще такой момент - можно все равно получить доступ к файлам.
Например если я зайду на домен/backend/config.js я увижу содержимое файла. Как запретить доступ файлам напрямую? Что бы люди методом тыка не могли гулять по файлам подобным

Answer (score 0):

Правилами доступа Order, Allow, Deny по группировке Location

```
<Location "/backend/public">  
    AllowOverride None  
    Order Allow, Deny  
    Allow from All  
</Location>  

<Location "/backend/">  
 AllowOverride None  
 Order Deny, Allow  
 Deny from All  
 Allow from 10.10.10.10   
</Location>
```